# Rails 3 as_json :only or :methods option do not work with dynamic attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

in one of my Rails 3 controllers I need to return jSON response with only couple of attributes on the model, so I used

```
respond_with foo_list :only => [:id, :name], :methods => []
```

but still in the resposne I see more than just these 2 attributes, I noticed that those undesirable attributes are actually dynamic attributes generated from the query select function:

```
foo_list = Foo.select("count(bar) as dattr1, sum(adafsd) as dattr2")....
```

is there a way to work around this? or I have to build the hash myself?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conventional way to do this is to use the #as_json method on ActiveRecord that automatically converts an object to it's json representation.

You can override it with whatever attributes you want:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  # minimal
  if options[:minimal].present?
    {id: self.id, name: self.name }
  # default
  else
    super
  end
end

...

my_model = MyModel.find(...)
my_model.as_json 
my_model.as_json(:minimal)
```

Comment: Wouldn't calling self.as_json within the self.as_json cause a recursive call that never ends? I tried this myself and I get a 'stack level too deep'.

Comment: You should super inside as_json() and not self.as_json: result = super(options.reverse_merge(:except => :html_code))

Comment: Yeah I fixed it, sorry about that!